# For which $s$ is defined $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{ \left( \zeta(s) \right) ^n}$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, absolute-convergence, cauchy-product

Unless I'm making a mistake, if one of the factors $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ of a **convolution product or Cauchy product** converges, and the other $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ corverges absolutely then the product $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}  b_{n-k+1}$$
converges.

For $n\geq 1$ I've computed this product, **without formality**, for $a_n=b_n=\frac{1}{(\zeta(s))^n}$ where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function and those $s$ such that $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ (for example I know that for $\Re s>1$ the Riemann Zeta funciton doesn't vanish). Then I've computed  without formality 
$$ \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{ \left( \zeta(s) \right) ^n}\right)^2= \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{ \left( \zeta(s) \right) ^n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{ \left( \zeta(s) \right) ^n}.$$

> **Question.** For wich $s$ does make sense the previous product? I say for some easy region in the whole plane, if my problem is well posed you can study the more advance topic, but to me is enough for easy regions. **Thanks in advance.**

My only computation was that I belive that for those $s\neq 0$ with $|\Re\zeta(s)|>1$ I can write 
$$ \left|  \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{ \left( \zeta(s) \right) ^n}\right| \leq \frac{1}{1-|\zeta(s)|}-1=\frac{|\zeta(s)|}{|\zeta(s)|-1}.$$

Comment: IN my last computation was a typo the right is $|\zeta(s)|>1$ intead of $|\Re \zeta(s)|>1$.

Comment: of course for considering $\sum_n z^n$ as a series (and not only a formal series) you need $|z| < 1$, hence here $|\zeta(s)| > 1$, in particular this is true for $s$ in the neighborhood of $]1,\infty[$. and here you don't need your first assumption : if $\sum_n |a_n|$ and $\sum_n |b_n|$ both converge then $\sum_{n,m} a_n b_m$ converges absolutely, hence the order of summation doesn't matter and $(\sum_n a_n)(\sum_m b_m) = \sum_n \sum_k a_k b_{n-k}$

Comment: Very thanks much for your contribution, you are welcome to add an answer @user1952009

Comment: Many thanks @PreservedFruit